# Билды в teamcity не проходят из-за имён файлов

Tags: c#, .net, teamcity

Всем привет.
Может кто сталкивался с таким.
В вижуалке билды запускаются и проходят успешно. Но в teamcity билд падает в ошибку так как файлы проекта не найдены.
Обнаружил, что ищет файлы с именами в нижнем регистре (все маленькие буквы), а файлы есть на агенте, но у них в наименовании есть буквы с верхним регистром.
Получается что в коде задействован файл test, а по факту он называется Test.
Есть ли возможность, где-то в teamcity подкрутить, чтобы на регистр не обращалось внимание?

Comment: Вообще работа с файлами - ответственность операционной системы. В Windows например регистронезависимая система доступа к файлам, а в Linux зачастую регистрозависимая, поэтому вам стоит просто привести имена файлов в соответствие с тем что написано в путях к ним.

Comment: Полагаю, это и есть ответ. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще работа с файлами - ответственность операционной системы.

В Windows например регистронезависимая система доступа к файлам, а в Linux зачастую регистрозависимая, поэтому вам стоит просто привести имена файлов в соответствие с тем что написано в путях к ним.